# NodeJS - Mongoose document embedding

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-schema

I am trying to practice Mongoose and Node JS, I want to use Comment schema in Article schema and when I run the server, it just throws an error like this:

> Invalid value for schema Array path `comments`

Here is my Comment model

```
module.exports = function( mongoose ) {

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var CommentSchema = new Schema({
        text: String,
        author: String,
        createDate: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });

    console.log("********");    
    console.log(CommentSchema);
    console.log("********");

    mongoose.model( 'Comment', CommentSchema);
};
```

And my Article model:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose){
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Comment = require("./Comment");

    console.log("--------");
    console.log(mongoose);
    console.log("--------");

    var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        content: String,
        author: String,
        comments: [Comment.schema],
        createDate: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });
    mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
};
```

They are in the same folder called "models".

And finally my app.js to show the bindings:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require("morgan");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var utils = require("./lib/utils");
var config = require("config");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongooseConnection = utils.connectToDatabase(mongoose, config.db);
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: true});

require("./controllers/ArticleController")(app, mongooseConnection);
require("./controllers/CommentController")(app, mongooseConnection);
require("./controllers/IndexController")(app, mongooseConnection);

require("./models/Article")(mongooseConnection);
require("./models/Comment")(mongooseConnection);
require("./models/User")(mongooseConnection);

app.listen(app.get("port"), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port" + app.get("port"));
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't recall needing to pass the connection to the schema/model. Just get rid of that stuff and export the model.

Answer (score 2):

At your `./models/Article.js` your variable `Comment` is a function (you should be invoking it with parenthesis passing by the mongoose variable), instead of the Comment model:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose){
    // some code ..

    var Comment = require("./Comment");

    // some code ..
};
```

And even if you execute your function above passing by the mongoose variable at your `./models/Comments.js` in your function, you are basically returning nothing:

```
module.exports = function( mongoose ) {
    // some code ..

    mongoose.model( 'Comment', CommentSchema);
};
```

---

So try this example that I created below.

Comment Model at `./models/Comment.js`:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose) {
  var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String,
    createDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  });

  return mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
};
```

Article Model at `./models/Article.js`:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose) {
  var Comment = require('./Comment')(mongoose);

  var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: String,
    comments: [Comment.schema],
    createDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  });

  return mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
};
```

Main file at `./app.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoose_sky');

var Article = require('./models/Article.js')(mongoose);

var article = new Article({
  title: 'my article',
  content: 'this is my awesome article',
  author: 'wilson',
  comments: [
    {
      text: 'hey your article is great',
      author: 'doug'
    },
    {
      text: 'hillarious!',
      author: 'john'
    }
  ]
});

article.save(function (err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('article was saved');
    console.log(article);
  }
});
```